# Digits of $\pi$ in other bases?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pi, experimental-mathematics

Pi day got me interested in thinking about whether $\pi$ is a normal number - one whose digits are uniformly distributed no matter what base the number is written in. The [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A068436) for $\pi$ in base 11 only has a hundred or so digits, and they do not look uniform at all (e.g., 5 shows up almost three times as often as 4 does).

I wrote some crummy R code this morning to generate digits of pi in base 11, and it worked until floating point arithmetic started causing problems, so my numbers disagree with OEIS after about the 13th decimal place. (As an interesting aside, my 300 or so incorrect digits of $\pi$ in base 11 *do* look uniform.)

My question is, are many digits of $\pi$ in other bases stored somewhere online? I need to look at many more than just a hundred. If not, has any work been done on finding an algorithm that could calculate the digits correctly? Where would I start looking up this sort of stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do write R code (or some other language) shouldn't it be easier to get the correct expansion in base 10 from somewhere (didn't check but that should be easy to find for a lot of digits) and convert that to base 11? I would have to think a bit how to implement that efficiently but I don't think this should run into issues with floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Oh and if you manage to prove something about the normality of $\pi$, I think this would count as a major break through. As far as I know, nobody seriously doubts the normality of $\pi$ but there is very little rigorously proven.

Comment: Conversion to hexadecimal is an important method to confirm claimed decimal expansions: a [BBP type spigot algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Spigot_algorithms) is used to calculate random hex digits near the end of the expansion and compared with the converted hex result.

Comment: @quarague, the code is bad. Basically you figure out the highest power of the base that is less than the argument, and continue subtracting successively smaller powers of the base, storing the results of integer division as the digits. You end up dividing small numbers by small numbers, and so I think rounding errors could compound easily here.

Comment: @NickD, thank you. I'll check that next time I cook up an expansion.

Comment: http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/pi/pibases.html  ?? 10 different bases it seems.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) gives thousands of digits for your choice of base; e.g., `RealDigits[Pi, 11, 10000][[1]]` gives $10000$ digits of $\pi$ in base $11$.

Comment: @r.e.s. That syntax didn't work for me. I entered it for **base 12** expecting A and B values (**3.184809493`b`918664573`a`62**...), but it returned just regular pi. Any idea why? Finally I got base 12 by entering `Pi to base 12` and clicking the "More digits" button repeatedly.

Comment: @r.e.s. Never mind... I see what `RealDigits` does now. Also, it seems 10000 is currently too many digits for it to calculate, and it gives up without giving clear user feedback that it gives up (just shows pi). Entering 5000 instead worked.

Comment: @Mentalist In case you may be interested: In SageMath, `x=pi; ndigits=10^6; b=12; floor((x - floor(x)) * b**ndigits).digits(base=b)[::-1]` gives a million digits in a few seconds.